# Support for SP 2013 RTM version in Windows Server 2012 R2 OS

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, installation, windows-server-2012-r2

I have installed SharePoint Server 2013 in a Windows Server 2012 R2-based environment.

I am getting many issues. After the installation site pages library, or any other document libraries created are not working.

When I navigate to the pages library, or site pages library or any custom list created, it shows

> Sorry, something went wrong.

Is this because SP 2013 RTM version is not supported in WIN 2012 R2 OS?

**UPDATE:**
My SP 2013 Version :15.0.4569.1506
I checked the  build numbers, 15.0.4569.1506  is for SP1  only.
Now I wonder why, i am getting the errors  for doc.libs, new apps, home page url etc.

Comment: I just finished yesterday a two-server-farm with SharePoint Server 2013 on Windows Server 2012 R2. Everything worked. I used autospinstaller.com for installation.

Comment: For 2012 R2 you should need SharePoint 2013 SP1 for it to even install without hacks? Pretty sure it is not supported prior to SP1 anyway

Answer (score 6):

It is not supported to install SharePoint 2013 RTM on Windows Server 2012 R2.

It was supported first with the release of the SharePoint 2013 SP1 slipstream release.

Please see this KB article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2891274

Comment: I got the error " the installation of the package failed", after i downloaded the SP1 and tried to run the exe

Comment: i downloaded this from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2817458"